# XSLT filter unique nodes within a group using Muenchian Grouping Method

Tags: xslt, filter, unique, grouping

I am following this article about the [Muenchian Grouping Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) as reference.

In my problem, within each group, some values for the `<forename>`node can be duplicated, while I want to filter unique values. 
I tried applying the `forename[not(.=preceding-sibling::forename)]` 
selection criteria, but this is not working as I get to see duplicates in the output.

The XSLT I am testing follows (which is basically exactly the same as the article above bar the "isolated" line where the extra filter is applied).

I am obviously getting this wrong. What is the problem here?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="contacts-by-surname" match="contact" use="surname" />
    <xsl:template match="records">
        <xsl:for-each select="contact[count(. | key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="surname" />
            <xsl:value-of select="surname" />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('contacts-by-surname', surname)">
                <xsl:sort select="forename" />


                <xsl:value-of select="forename[not(.=preceding-sibling::forename)]" />


            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do two-level grouping with another key

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="contacts-by-surname" match="contact" use="surname" />
    <xsl:key name="contacts-by-full-name" match="contact" use="concat(surname, '|', forename)" />
    <xsl:template match="records">
        <xsl:for-each select="contact[count(. | key('contacts-by-surname', surname)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="surname" />
            <xsl:value-of select="surname" />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('contacts-by-surname', surname)
                [count(. | key('contacts-by-full-name',
                               concat(surname, '|', forename'))[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:sort select="forename" />
                <xsl:value-of select="forename" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here, within each `surname` group I'm doing another Muenchian grouping on the full name (surname|forename) and extracting just the first instance of each forename within the set of contacts with that surname.

Comment: works like a charm! Now I only need to look at it and understand it.. thanks!